# Focus not being set by method to grab focus

Tags: java, setfocus

Learning to code, building a GUI to figure out how everything interacts.  Trying to write a method to set focus on (component) at the points I need in the larger program - ie to call `FocusGrabber(JTextField1)` and have it set the input focus on `JTextField1`.  In an attempt to do my best SSCCE, I've made a simple main that makes just enough GUI to give 2 textfields that should set focus on the second.

```
package ODIN;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
/*
*/
class FocusGrabber implements Runnable {
    private JComponent component;
    public FocusGrabber(JComponent component) {
        this.component = component;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        component.grabFocus();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //draw and show the GUI
        JFrame GUI = new JFrame();
        GUI.setTitle("New Provider Interface");
        GUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JTextField textID = new JTextField("providerID ", 20);
        final JTextField textName = new JTextField("Provider Name ", 20);

        GUI.add(textID);
        GUI.add(textName);
        GUI.pack();
        GUI.setVisible(true);
        FocusGrabber(textName);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `requestFocusInWindow` over `grabFocus`...

It would also be helpful if you called the `run` method at some point

Also, shouldn't it be more like

```
FocusGrabber fg = new FocusGrabber(textName);
fg.run();
```

Comment: yes it should - I was trying to transcribe over a bare minimal main for SSCCE and I missed that part of it.  Defining the focusgrabbers as variables in the main rather than as responses inside eventlisteners, and then running them as needed, worked perfectly.